# What design/feature aspects assist in visitor conversion rates?

Tags: website-design, registration

Web design being around for so long, I would imagine we have some rules or guidelines regarding this topic. When a user visits your website for the first time, what particulars have been shown to take that visitor and transform them into a member/customer? There must be some proven methods of doing things -- something that shows a big cartoony graphic isn't the best way to do conversion (or maybe it is).

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking of things like, login box in a clear spot, simple graphics, showing the product, etc...

In my own searching I just keep hitting websites that talk about UI design of registration forms themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some more advanced conversion-centric design tips at Smashing Magazine:

[Design To Sell: 8 Useful Tips To Help Your Website Convert](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/06/design-to-sell-12-tips-to-help-your-website-convert/)

[7 More Useful Tips To Help Your Site Convert](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/13/7-more-useful-tips-to-help-your-site-convert/)

You might also like [NeuroMarketing.com](http://www.neurosciencemarketing.com/blog/) and similar sites with a focus on cognitive science and marketing.